# Mongoose: I need subdocuments to generate "_id" instead of "id" to search through array of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm following along with the book "Getting MEAN" by Simon Holmes, however, I have stumbled on an issue regarding subdocument ids. I am trying to request a "review document" inside a "Location document" using the "[MongooseDocumentArray.id(id)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray.id) helper function provided by the mongoose docs. However, all my subdocuments generate "id" but the previously mentioned function requires "_id" instead thus returning "null" object.

> Function description: Searches array items for the first document with a matching _id.

What is the issue here? My parent document being "Location" generates its id with "_id", which baffles me even more... The nested schema setup, the returned location object from a database containing the review sub documents and the controller function for the route doing the querying are illustrated in following code snippets respectively.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({    
    author: String,
    rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
    reviewText: String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    address: String,
    rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
    facilities: [String],
    coords: {type: [Number], index: "2dsphere"},
    reviews: [reviewSchema]   
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

[Returned Location object showing subdocuments containing id instead of _id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqnRd.png)

For the following snippet, this is the relevant route:

```
router.get("/locations/:locationid/reviews/:reviewid", ctrlReviews.reviewsReadOne);



module.exports.reviewsReadOne = function(req, res){ 
if(req.params && req.params.locationid && req.params.reviewid){
    Loc.findById(req.params.locationid)
        .select("name reviews")
        .exec(function(err, location) {
            var response, review;
            if(location.reviews && location.reviews.length > 0){                    
                // This returns zero, because the function requires _id
                // but all subdocuments have path/properties called id
                review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid);
                console.log(review);

                if(!review){
                    sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
                        "message": "reviewid not found"
                    });
                } else {
                    response = {
                        location: {
                            name: location.name,
                            id : req.params.locationid
                        },
                        review: review
                    };
                    sendJsonResponse(res, 200, response);
                }
            }
    })
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema to the following.

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    address: String,
    rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
    facilities: [String],
    coords: {type: [Number], index: "2dsphere"},
    reviews: [{
       author: String,
       rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
       reviewText: String,
       createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now
    }]    
});
```

Comment: I'll check this solution out as soon as I manage to fix my database connections, have some issues reconnecting after full system reinstall.

Comment: it doesn' work. I still get the same problem. Any other ideas will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm reading this book, the book is awesome, give a lot of information about a simple and optimize architecture for a MEAN stack, the problem was in the code in the book when use:

$push:{reviews:{author: 'Simon Holmes',**id:Objectid()**,...

in this code use **id** instead of **_id**, so the correct script is:

*db.locations.update({name:'Starcups'},{$push:{reviews:{author: 'Simon Holmes',**_id:ObjectId()**,rating:5,timestamp:new Date("Jul 16,2013"),reviewText:"What a great place. I can't say enougn good about it"}}});*

"When adding a new sub-doc through the Mongo shell you need to specify the id as _id. " (Holmes S.)
 https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/35152.page